# php dentro de Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, api

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un botón html, el cual llamo con php, par que me realice una función de descontar (-1) con una api, poniéndolo así me funciona perfecto el descontar y me muestra el resultado. Pero antes de descontar quiero que salga un alert con JS, preguntando si está seguro de descontar y si da si entonces que se ejecute la api en php.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'descontar') {
            ?>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            x = window.confirm('¿Está Seguro de Descontar?');
            if (x == true) {
             <?php //aquí empieza la api que descuenta
$Mostrar_saldo = file_get_contents('http://api.xxx.com/suscriptor/index/id_usuario/00006/id_suscripcion/000');
         $Mostrar = json_decode($Mostrar_saldo, true);
         $my_array = array_shift($Mostrar);
         $saldo = $my_array['saldo'];
         echo "<br>";
         print "Saldo Anterior: $my_array[saldo]"; 
         echo "<br>";
         $nuevo_saldo = $saldo - 1;
         $actualiza_saldo = (file_get_contents('http://api.xxx.com/suscriptor/actualizar/id_usuario/000/id_suscripcion/000/saldo/'.$nuevo_saldo));
         $actualiza = json_decode($actualiza_saldo, true);

         $my_array = array_shift($actualiza);
         echo "Saldo Actual: $nuevo_saldo";
             ?> //aquí termina la api que descuenta
            return true;
            }else{
                  document.write ("No continuar. Elija una Opción");
                  return false;
                }
            </script>
            <?php
            }
```

Con éste código, funciona la api y descuenta normalmente, pero no me muestra ninguna alerta, ni el echo que dice el saldo.

Comment: Estimado @giselle debes tener en cuenta que **php** se ejecuta en el servidor y **javascript** en el cliente (**browser**), por tanto no puedes mezclar el uso de ambos al mismo tiempo.

Comment: Esto perfectamente lo puedes hacer todo con **javascript** o su librería **jquery**. No entiendo para que metes **php** si este se ejecuta como controlador, y lo que esta haciendo es solo por el lado del cliente.

Comment: Este es un problema claro porque no tienes en cuenta las buenas prácticas de desarrollo de software. **Nunca mezcles** código cliente con servidor, es realmente malo ya que promueves la alta cohesión y rompes el principio de responsabilidad única. Simple y llanamente escribe tu código cliente y mediante AJAX por ejemplo, haz que se comunique con el backend.

Comment: Gracias. Y claro que puedo hacerlo con JS, estoy con php porque tengo enlace a la base de datos con php, 4 botones de los que necesito información de las consultas realizadas a la base de datos, también con php, si puedo conectar la base de datos con javascript me gustaría que me dijeras, o si las llamadas a las consultas se puede hacer desde JS a php, es decir, JS dentro de php que sería lo contrario a mi pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es lo siguiente.

En la interfaz, o sea, el formulario o donde este el botón debes agregar el siguiente código en javascript, yo por comodidad lo escribo usando Jquery.

```
$("button").on("click",function(){
   var confirmar = confirm("¿Desea hacer algo con este botón?");
   if (confirmar){
      $.post("url-pagina-php",{"action":"descontar"},function(){
         alert("ya se descontó lo que debía descontar);
      })
   }
})
```

Por otro lado en una pagina PHP debes poner todo el código que publicaste al comienzo.

¿Como funciona? Se va a ejecutar una pagina, la que tiene el javascript pero no realizara nada hasta que el usuario presione el botón y presione en aceptar. Una vez que eso ocurra, recién ahí llamara a la pagina PHP.

Ahora si lo quieres todo en la misma pagina y corriendo a la vez no es posible ya que primero se arma el código PHP (se ejecuta en el servidor) y posteriormente se ejecuta el código Javascript (en el navegador del cliente).